Postgres Overlapping Groups/Reusing rows between groups
I have a table ordered by some column A. I would like to perform an aggregation on n rows at a time but I'd also like to incorporate the previous k and the next k' rows as context.
For example, let's say I have the following data ordered by A.



A
B




0
2


1
3


2
7


3
4


4
3


5
2



aggregating n rows is as simple as group by A / n. For the case n=2 that would give us the groups (on A) [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]. An example query may be to get the sum:
with my_table(A, B) as (
    values
    (0, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2)
)
select A / 2 as A_2, sum(B)
from my_table
group by A / 2

outputs:



A_2
sum(B)




0
5


1
11


2
5



What I find difficult is to get overlapping groups. Let's say k = k' = 2. Then I'd like to get the groups (on A): [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]
Is there a way to do so in postgres? either through group by or window functions?
I'd like to do something like:
with my_table(A, B) as (
    values
    (0, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2)
)
select ??? as ???, sum(B)
from my_table
group by ???

giving an output.



A_???
B




0
16


1
21


2
16



sum is used here as just an example. I'd like to do any arbitrary aggregate. It also does not have to be in a single CTE.
I think you would call such a thing a sliding window with overlap

You can use a window function for this, then filter afterwards using modulo division.
with my_table(A, B) as (
    values
    (0, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2)
),
running as (
    select *,
      sum(B) over (order by A rows between 2 preceding and 3 following) as running_sum
    from my_table
)
select *
from running
where A % 2 = 0;

db<>fiddle
